# Proof that if a square matrix has a row of zeroes, the square matrix is non-invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

I will like to make sure my mathematical reasoning is sound as I am new to proof.

Can someone with mathematical maturity help me confirm that my proof is sound?

1. $AX = 0$, given any $A$ square matrix with a row of zeroes.
2. A row of zeroes means that there is a non-zero vector $X$ as a
   solution to $AX = 0$ (means the column without pivot can be of any solution)
3. For the sake of argument, assuming that there is $A^{-1}$:

   $A^{-1}AX = A^{-1}0$
   $X = 0$, Since  $A^{-1}A$ gives identity matrix and product of any $0$ gives $0$

Since X has a non-zero vector solution(point 2), by proof of contradiction, $A^{-1}$ does not exist. Since $A^{-1}$ does not exist, by definition, matrix $A$ is non-invertible.

Comment: You have your terminology backwards: the fact that $A^{-1}$ does not exist — which is true when $A$ has a row of zeroes — means that $A$ is **not** invertible. You can also say that $A$ is *singular*.

Comment: Hi @BrianM.Scott thanks for the fast reply, trying to find the line of reasoning why when $A$ has a row of zeroes, it leads to no $A^{−1}$. Is it because by definition   $A^{−1}A=I$, since $A$ has a row of zeroes the matrix multiplication of any matrix will result in a matrix solution with a row of zeroes which means there won't be an identity matrix?

Comment: thanks @sathish for the edits -.-" yes i meant non-invertible!

Comment: Suppose that row $k$ of $A$ is all zero. Let $X$ be the vector that has a $1$ in position $k$ and zeroes everywhere else. Then $X\ne 0$, but $AX=0$, so $A$ cannot be invertible: if $A^{-1}$ existed, we’d have $A^{-1}AX=IX=X$, not $0$.

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct, although I think you should explain how you know point 1 is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but it's overly complicated. You tried to prove that $A$ is singular (i.e. $AX=0$ for some nonzero $X$) and use this fact to prove that $A$ is non-invertible (i.e. $A$ has no inverse), but it's actually easier to prove that $A$ is non-invertible directly.

Suppose the $k$-th row of $A$ is zero. Then the $k$-th row of $AB$ is zero for every matrix $B$. Therefore $AB\ne I$ for every matrix $B$, i.e. $A$ has no inverse.

Answer (score 0):

More generally $ A $ will have no inverse if the rows (or columns) of A are linearly dependent. However , I assume you are new to linear algebra and linear dependence has not been introduced to you yet.

In that case, let

AX=Y

where X and Y are column matrices.

If AX=Y has a single solution, then for every Y there exists only one X.
We can find X by $X=A^{-1}Y $

You seem to be aware that if A has a zero row (or many zero rows), the equation $AX=0$ has many solutions..

If $AX=0$ has only a single solution, its the trivial one.. namely X is the zero column.

Hope you get the drift. $A^{-1} $ exists whenever the equation AX=Y has a single solution. A row of zeros (or linearly dependent rows) makes the system have multiple solutions and hence no inverse is possible.

If you are introduced to matrices for solving a system of simultaneous equations, a zero row means you have one less equation in your system.. You need three equations to solve for three unknowns. if you are given only two equations, (which is what a zero row means) , you will obviously have multiple solutions. And whenever there are multiple solutions, system is not invertible.

Therefore, your proof is a direct consequence of existence of non-trivial X such that $AX=0$. If that is justified, your proof is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof works. 
Assuming the existence of an inverse leads you to
$AX=0 \Leftrightarrow A^{-1} A X = 0$. As you assumed $X$ to be nontrivial this is a contradiction since $A^{-1} A X = X$. 
What you need to know in order for this to work is that there are nontrivial solutions to $AX = 0$. But since your matrix has a row of zeros this is given.